# Draw 5 cards from a deck of 52 without replacement, what is the probability that those 5 cards are in ascending or descending order?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, permutations, card-games

Need help double checking the answer for this one:
Firstly, calculate the probability of getting 5 distinct cards. This would be:

52/52 * 48/51 * 44/50 * 40/49 * 36/48 = p

Now, the probability of the cards being in ascending or descending order is 2/5! = 1/60.

Hence final probability is p/60.

Is this line of logic and answer correct?

Comment: The answer depends on what you mean by ascending (descending) order and whether an ace can be a high or low card.  For instance, is $A\clubsuit, A\spadesuit, \color{red}{2\diamondsuit}, \color{red}{5\heartsuit}, 7\spadesuit$ in ascending order?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Sorry, Ace is 1. And, no, I mean strictly ascending.

Comment: @N.F.Taussing I am curious now though. If the case was that ascending not strictly ascending, so that your example would work, I'm not sure how to calculate that.

Comment: In that case, your answer is correct.

Comment: The denominator would still be the same.  The numerator is trickier.  My inclination would be to consider cases, depending on how many cards of each rank there are, which involves considering partitions of five with no part larger than $4$.  Say we have four cards of one rank and one of the other.  Choose the rank with four cards, select all the cards of that rank, choose the rank of the other card, choose the suit of the card of that rank.   As in your original problem, the lower rank must be selected first, but we must take into account permutations of cards of the same rank.

Comment: That is the way I thought of doing the problem.